# Embed external Intent in main Activity

Tags: android, view, android-activity, embed

I have seen a number of examples of using an ActivityGroup to embed multiple Activites in a single view. In each of these cases, the Activities being loaded are internal to the current application. In addition, they all appear to take over the entire view.

I would like to start an external Activity using an Intent for a particular mime type. Specifically, if the device has a PDF viewer installed, I would like to start that Activity to view a PDF. However, I would like it to appear within the View of my running application Activity, keeping my main Activities header and footer Views intact.

Is it possible to load an external Activity within a View inside my running application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to load an external Activity within a View inside my running application?

No, sorry, that is not possible.

Comment: How does the the TabHost do it then?

Comment: @Shooshpanchick: `TabHost` does not supporting loading external activities. It will load *your* activities.