# How to Launch android apps within my application in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my application there is tab layout. and two tabs.

- tab 1 - my app  [image]
- tab 2 - any outside android app (like Contacts, call
  dialer etc.. ) (i know how to launch outside application but its not
  running within my application (means tab will not display after
  launch )).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read about the Intent class and learn what actions are and you will solve your problem. We will not give you the answer. Understand the way the android intent system works and then it will be gravy.

Comment: @JoxTraex Is it possible for what he is asking? then I have to read Intent again

Comment: is tat possible ? I doubt that . You can run other application from  your application but running it inside a view generated by first app?

Answer (score 12):

I may have misunderstood this, but unless you have created explicit [intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) (worked with the other app developer or created the other app you wish to embed) this will not be possible.

Each Android app runs in a sandbox: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html

Particularly:

> Because Android sandboxes applications from each other, applications
>   must explicitly share resources and data. They do this by declaring
>   the permissions they need for additional capabilities not provided by
>   the basic sandbox. Applications statically declare the permissions
>   they require, and the Android system prompts the user for consent at
>   the time the application is installed. Android has no mechanism for
>   granting permissions dynamically (at run-time) because it complicates
>   the user experience to the detriment of security.

Therefore this would not be possible. It seems misguided or malicious to begin with, but I would seriously reconsider your approach and rethink the benefits weighed against the unlikelihood of even being able to achieve what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

read doc (intent section), some example:

```
public class MyTab extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        Intent taskIntent = new Intent(this, Public.class);
        taskIntent.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, "public");

        TabHost.TabSpec tsValid = tabHost.newTabSpec("public");
        tsValid.setIndicator(getText(R.string.tab_title_public));
        tsValid.setContent(taskIntent);

        tabHost.addTab(tsValid);

        Intent annIntent = new Intent(this, Private.class);
        annIntent.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, "private");

        TabHost.TabSpec tsGenerate = tabHost.newTabSpec("private");
        tsGenerate.setIndicator(getText(R.string.tab_title_private));
        tsGenerate.setContent(annIntent);

        tabHost.addTab(tsGenerate);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this is not possible.

You can only display your own activies inside a `TabHost`. For external activities you would need an implicit intent, but `TabHost` does not support this: [Embed external Intent in main Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107204/embed-external-intent-in-main-activity)

Therefor you  display the data from a foreign application in your own activity. Do do this, you query the content provider the other application provides (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) in your list activity (see a complete example at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) and inclucde this `ListActivity` in your TabHost.